# Safari prompting for local user account password on Apple websites

Tags: macos, icloud, safari, apple-id

When navigating to an Apple login page in Safari on macOS 10.15 it shows a Apple ID login window and prompts me to enter my local user account password (not my Apple ID password). From what I can tell, this is a Safari feature and is not a part of the webpage.

[image: AppleID prompt]
[image: User password prompt on AppleID page]

Is there anyway to disable this? I have all Safari autofill settings turned off as I use a third-party password manager. It is super annoying to wait several seconds for this window to be displayed and then have to click "cancel" before I can log in.

#### EDIT

It appears there is no way to disable this behavior. I have opened an issue in Feedback Assistant (FB7582188). Feel free to dupe it. https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5003428010917888

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new feature with safari on macOS and Catalina when you are signed in to your iCloud / AppleID on trusted and keychain synchronized devices when communicating to some Apple secure services online.

Your local admin password unlocks they key store and sends a secure token rather than your iCloud password to authenticate you through Safari to Apple’s web site.

Ways to opt out:

- Sign out of iCloud on that Mac.
- Use a different browser.

Comment: That is a bummer. Do you know if this new feature is advertised/documented anywhere?

Comment: @AddisonWebb I will edit the answer as I reverse engineer this or learn more. Apple did the same thing on iOS (i.e. _use the device passcode instead of the account password_) It freaked a lot of people out as well. Big shift in the mental model and concept many people have with how authentication might be implemented versus how it actually is implemented with secure tokens, forward encryption, anti-playback defeat mitigations, salting passphrases, limiting plain text storage, etc...

Comment: I have opened an issue in Feedback Assistant (FB7582188). Feel free to dupe it. https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5003428010917888